# CompiledSwiftSources failed with a non-zero exit code

Tags: swift, xcode, swift-package-manager

I was recently using Xcode 13.4.1. Downloaded and installed the 14.3 beta. Deleted the beta completely, ran 13.4.1 and it wouldn’t build my project anymore. I don't receive any “errors”, I just get a warning saying, “Could not read serialized diagnostics file: error(“Failed to open diagnostics file”).” for a couple of my package dependencies(no specific package, shows the error for different ones everytime I try to build). Or sometimes I get the warning above AND an error that says, “CompiledSwiftSources failed with a non-zero exit code”.

At one point, I did see this warning, “Failed to retrieve search paths with pkg-config; maybe pkg-config is not installed.” I'm not seeing it anymore, but maybe it still applies?

I've tried cleaning my project, reset packages cache, deleting derived data, restarting Xcode, restarting my machine, deleting 13.4.1 and re-downloading it. No cigar.

Anyone else run into this and/or have an idea on how to resolve this?

Comment: Would you check your command line tools version? It's under Xcode Preferences > Locations

Comment: It may be set to nothing

Comment: @Jake the command line tools are set to 13.4.1.

Comment: Is your project using swift 5.7 or any other beta targeted software? If you started the project in xcode 14 beta, You may want to recreate the project in 13.4

Comment: No. Just Swift 5. Don’t see any other beta targeted software. Project wasn’t started on the beta. 

Something I did notice is the 15.5 simulators were gone once I went back to 13.4.1 and I think some of the errors I’ve seen for these SPM packages reference “iOSsimulators 15.5”. Weird thing is I can’t download the 15.5. Doesn’t show as an option. @Jake

Comment: It would help if you snapped a screen shot of the project and if you pasted the exact error log